# formula for Walsh-Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, binary

I've been given a problem about Walsh-Fourier series,tried to set formulas,used other theorems,but couldn't find a way out. Can anyone tell me hint?
The problem is as it states:

**Prove that** 
$$S_i(S_{2^s}f(x)) =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
S_{2^s}(f(x)), i>2^s\\ 
S_i(f(x)),i\le2^s \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $S_{n}f(x)$ is Walsh-Fourier series 
$S_nf(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{[0,1]}fw_k$ and  $w_k$ is Walsh function.If $k=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}k_i2^i$ and $x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x_j2^{-j}$ where $x_j \in \{0,1\}$  than $w_k(x)=(-1)^{\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}k_jx_j}$

Comment: You should provide definition for Walsh-Fourier series.

Comment: @RagingBoson sorry,edited

Comment: $S_n f$ is just the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto the span of $w_1,\dots,w_n$.